# SSL certicicate not working in cpanel

Tags: ssl, https, cpanel, cloudflare

Im using hostgator as my host.They do not provide free ssl certificate.So im using cloudflare free ssl certificate for my site.SSL certificate working everywhere except Cpanel.

I tried manually adding ssl through cpanel option.But not really working!Is there any way i can add it there?

Or it will be really good if my cpnael url **cpanel.site.com** won't just show up to that address.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the CloudFlare SSL certificate then there is no need to add that SSL certificate to yoru cpanel nor to your site. Read the cloudflare documentation in order to see how to create and use Page Rules and their SSL certificate. cPanel has nothing to do with it. CF works just fine with cPanel/WHM and pretty much with any other related hosting panel. Your site can be http only in cPnel and then you do the HTTPS redirection from Clouflare using their Flexible SSL and page rules

Answer (score 0):

cpanel.yourdomain.com ssl is related to server side. If your host allow autossl with Let's Encrypt (for example) then it will install ssl for all your necessary subdomains like webmail, cpanel, mail, www etc. If you are installing ssl manually, then you cannot install it for cpanel subdomain. However if you want to use cpanel securely and have enabled ssl with yourdomain.com the you can use it:
https://yourdomain.com:2083